# Need configuration for apache2 redirection to tomcat7 on Ubuntu Server 13.04 LTE x64

Tags: tomcat, configuration, apache2

This is regarding the apache2 listening on port 80 on Ubuntu 13.04LTE forwarding to tomcat7 on the same server but listening on port 8080.

After the installation when I looked at the configuration files, I see that apache2 is installed into many folders as below:

1. /usr/share/apache2 - I can see default-site in it with page "It Works" and it works when I type the hostname registered to my server.
2. /etc/apache2 - I can see the httpd.conf and apache2.conf files.

when I type 360-ov.com, i get the default site "It Works" but I need to redirect it to 360-ov.com:8080 for every request on 80 port.

I checked the configuration but need help with the configuration. I tried the documentation but it was not clear on mox_proxy from 80 to 8080. Kindly help. Thank you.

My httpd.conf:

```
ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 360-ov.com
</Proxy>
#ProxyPass /360ov http://360-ov.com:8080/360ov/homepage.htm
ProxyPass /360ov/* http://360-ov:8080/360ov/*
#ProxyPassReverse /3600v http://360-ov.com:8080/360ov/homepage.htm
ProxyPassReverse /360ov/* http://360-ov:8080/360ov/*
```

Regards,
Chandra

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with the below configuration in httpd.conf file. In case someone needs it.

in a clean httpd.conf add the below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://example:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://example:8080/
    ServerName example.com 
</VirtualHost>
```